# FFmpeg filter complex add audio file to video at specific points

Tags: ffmpeg

`atrim=0:2` starts fine when I play the video it plays the mp3 now how do I add a working end time say finish at 9 seconds?

**Summary** I want to start at **2** seconds and finish at **9** seconds.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\vaastav song .mp4" -i "C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\2.mp3" -filter_complex "[0]atrim=0:2[Apre];[0]atrim=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[Apost];[Apre][1][Apost]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1" -vcodec copy -y "C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\output1.mp4"
```

log file

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-04-13-59e3a9a Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.102 / 56. 42.102
  libavcodec     58. 78.102 / 58. 78.102
  libavformat    58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.101 /  7. 77.101
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\vaastav song .mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-09-02T04:28:46.000000Z
  Duration: 00:05:08.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2289 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2160 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-09-02T04:28:46.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 09/01/2018.
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-09-02T04:28:46.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 09/01/2018.
Input #1, mp3, from 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\2.mp3':
  Metadata:
    genre           : Electronic;Indie
    title           : A Distorted Noise With A Little Bit Of Sense
    artist          : Lenin Was A Zombie
    encoder         : Lavf56.19.100
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
  Duration: 00:00:54.00, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 192 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.21
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> atrim
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> atrim
  Stream #1:0 (mp3float) -> concat:in1:a0
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (aac)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\output1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.78.102 aac
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2160 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-09-02T04:28:46.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 09/01/2018.
frame=  737 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=    7936kB time=00:00:29.44 bitrate=2208.1kbits/s speed=58.9x    
[out_0_0 @ 000000000312c900] 100 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.
[out_0_0 @ 000000000312c900] 1000 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong.
frame= 1401 fps=876 q=-1.0 size=   16640kB time=00:01:46.85 bitrate=1275.7kbits/s speed=66.8x    
frame= 2281 fps=1086 q=-1.0 size=   26112kB time=00:02:22.01 bitrate=1506.3kbits/s speed=67.6x    
frame= 3152 fps=1212 q=-1.0 size=   35584kB time=00:02:56.58 bitrate=1650.8kbits/s speed=67.9x    
frame= 4011 fps=1294 q=-1.0 size=   45824kB time=00:03:31.32 bitrate=1776.4kbits/s speed=68.2x    
frame= 4882 fps=1356 q=-1.0 size=   56320kB time=00:04:06.03 bitrate=1875.2kbits/s speed=68.3x    
frame= 5753 fps=1403 q=-1.0 size=   66560kB time=00:04:40.79 bitrate=1941.8kbits/s speed=68.5x    
frame= 6622 fps=1440 q=-1.0 size=   77056kB time=00:05:15.37 bitrate=2001.6kbits/s speed=68.6x    
frame= 7482 fps=1467 q=-1.0 size=   85248kB time=00:05:50.20 bitrate=1994.1kbits/s speed=68.7x    
frame= 7720 fps=1479 q=-1.0 Lsize=   87248kB time=00:05:59.79 bitrate=1986.5kbits/s speed=68.9x    
video:81451kB audio:5634kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.186449%
[aac @ 0000000003017ac0] Qavg: 648.065
```

I tried messing about with the line of code but no success so I turn to you for additional support

Comment: *"I want to start at 2 seconds and finish at 9 seconds."* Is not very clear. From which file? So final duration is 7 seconds?

Comment: video duration can be from 0 second to 10 hours am saying, i want to replace audio from 2 seconds to 9 seconds with mp3 file. replace audio from video audio with mp3 audio start time end time., the code shows it all i just need a working end time to this